# Regular Expression For Finding N Upper Case In Given String

Tags: regex

I am looking for the regular expression where i will pass a number from my code and in the given string it should allow that number of uppercase letters minimum.

I have tried the regular expression pattern

**[A-Z]{2}**

But It allowing only consecutive Uppercase

My required valid scenarios are

```
HeLlo
HEllo
HELLo
HELLO
heLLO
```

Thanks In advance

Comment: Can you show some examples which is valid and not valid?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your regex like,

```
(.*?[A-Z]){2}
```

If you pass 2, it should match all the strings having atleast two uppercase letters. Likewise it works for 1,2,.. n